# Inverse of a composite function: Conditions

Tags: calculus, functions

I know that the outer function(f) decides the range of the composite function(fog(x)) and the inner function(g) decides its domain.
Also for a functions inverse to exist, it should be one-one and onto.
So by this logic, fog(x) should be bijective for its inverse to exist.
What should I do further? Any help will be deeply appreciated.[the answer is (3) f is one one and g is onto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPfXa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observation that the composition is bijective is indeed the essential one. Break it down into the 2 properties, onto and 1-to-1.

For example, to show the onto property of $g$ use the onto property of $g\circ f$: Let $y\in C$, that means there is an $x\in A$ such that $g(f(x)) =y$ since $g\circ f$ is onto. But notice that now you also have a $b\in B$ such that $g(b) =y$ namely $b=f(x)$. Therefore g is onto.

Now do something similar with f and 1-to-1.
And lastly, you have to show an example where the composition is bijective, but f isn't onto and g isn't 1-to-1. (Hint: Play around with functions which are bijective depending on what domain or codomain you define them on like for example the square function.)
You should be able to figure out the rest.